# Save *.csv without spaces and double quote (2)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to save CSV data without double quotes.

```
# Write the data sets to CSV files
training_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'training_set.csv'), index=False, header=False)
validation_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'validation_set.csv'), index=False, header=False)
test_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'test_set.csv'), index=False, header=False)
```

The above source code is saving data with double quotes:

```
... ... ...
"76,GLU,H,5.406,5.079,6.304,0,0,0,1,1,0"
"172,THR,H,6.651,8.414,9.157,0,0,0,0,0,0"
"238,GLU,C,5.764,9.526,11.865,0,0,0,0,2,0"
"133,LYS,C,7.412,9.808,11.162,0,0,0,0,1,0"
"247,ASP,C,5.351,6.6,9.927,0,0,0,2,4,0"
"133,GLU,H,5.498,5.134,6.529,0,0,0,0,1,0"
"111,GLN,C,6.674,9.082,9.925,0,0,0,0,1,0"
"374,SER,C,6.642,8.332,11.536,0,0,0,0,1,0"
"192,SER,C,6.346,8.69,12.18,0,1,2,4,9,0"
"182,LEU,H,5.453,7.862,8.894,0,0,0,0,4,0"
... ... ...
```

If I write the following, then the compiler asks for an escape character:

```
# Write the data sets to CSV files
training_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'training_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
validation_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'validation_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
test_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'test_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Then, I wrote the following and error occured:

```
# Write the data sets to CSV files
training_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'training_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')
validation_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'validation_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')
test_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'test_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_split_segregate.py", line 87, in <module>
    training_set.to_csv(os.path.join(output_dir, target_dir, 'training_set.csv'), index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, escapechar='')
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3482, in to_csv
    storage_options=storage_options,
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1105, in to_csv
    csv_formatter.save()
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 257, in save
    self._save()
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 262, in _save
    self._save_body()
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 300, in _save_body
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "/home/my_username/heca_v2/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 316, in _save_chunk
    self.writer,
  File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 72, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

How can I resolve this issue?

**NOTE:** The source data does not have double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that your source data is a single column of comma separated data; something like:

```
                                       text
0    76,GLU,H,5.406,5.079,6.304,0,0,0,1,1,0
1   172,THR,H,6.651,8.414,9.157,0,0,0,0,0,0
2  238,GLU,C,5.764,9.526,11.865,0,0,0,0,2,0
3  133,LYS,C,7.412,9.808,11.162,0,0,0,0,1,0
4     247,ASP,C,5.351,6.6,9.927,0,0,0,2,4,0
5   133,GLU,H,5.498,5.134,6.529,0,0,0,0,1,0
6   111,GLN,C,6.674,9.082,9.925,0,0,0,0,1,0
7  374,SER,C,6.642,8.332,11.536,0,0,0,0,1,0
8    192,SER,C,6.346,8.69,12.18,0,1,2,4,9,0
9   182,LEU,H,5.453,7.862,8.894,0,0,0,0,4,0
```

If that is `df`, then `df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)` will produce the output you are seeing.

To generate a CSV column for each value in that column, you'll need to split it on `,` and `expand` to new columns. Using the sample df above:

```
df['text'].str.split(',', expand=True).to_csv(index=False, header=False)
```

Output:

```
76,GLU,H,5.406,5.079,6.304,0,0,0,1,1,0
172,THR,H,6.651,8.414,9.157,0,0,0,0,0,0
238,GLU,C,5.764,9.526,11.865,0,0,0,0,2,0
133,LYS,C,7.412,9.808,11.162,0,0,0,0,1,0
247,ASP,C,5.351,6.6,9.927,0,0,0,2,4,0
133,GLU,H,5.498,5.134,6.529,0,0,0,0,1,0
111,GLN,C,6.674,9.082,9.925,0,0,0,0,1,0
374,SER,C,6.642,8.332,11.536,0,0,0,0,1,0
192,SER,C,6.346,8.69,12.18,0,1,2,4,9,0
182,LEU,H,5.453,7.862,8.894,0,0,0,0,4,0
```